# whats a good visual studio dark theme for doing presentations?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I do presentations at user groups and I have a dark theme that just doesn't work with a projector. I don't like the default white. What is a good dark theme for visual stusio that works well with projectors? These are VGA projectors, not HD.

The lighting is generally not that bright directly in front of the screen, but it's isnt that dark in the room either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some more

[Studio Styles](http://studiostyl.es/)

I personally like 
[Coding Instinct](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/coding-instinct-theme)
although I have not experienced it with a projector.

Comment: Coding Instinct looks promising. I'll try it out and see. I've tried most of the ones on Studio Styles.

Comment: Coding Instinct looks pretty good with minor tweaks (probably dependant on the projector and lighting).

Answer (score 5):

Here are several that work in VS2008/VS2010

[Scott Hanselman's ComputerZen](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx)

or [StudioStyles](http://studiostyl.es/schemes)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried all of the ones from ScottH's blog and most of the Studio Styles. Not all of them but most of them. Is there any specific one you would suggest trying?

Comment: I switch between HumaneStudio and Son of Obsidian.  Both are easy on my eyes although they are light vs dark schemed

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these out soon as I'm in the same situation.